# Invalid Credentials - Youtube API and OAuth

Tags: php, api, oauth, youtube

I'm trying to send a blank video to a youtube account to see whether the youtube API connects to my gmail account or not. The thing is, it worked once and then it does not work anymore.

Here is my code.

```
    require ('youtube.php');
$youtube_settings = new YoutubeManager();
$client_id = $youtube_settings->clientID;
$client_secret = $youtube_settings->client_secret;

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri('http://foo.fr/youtube/upload');
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');

$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
session_start();

if(isset($_GET['code'])){
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    header('Location : http://foo.fr/youtube/upload');
    die();

}

if(isset($_SESSION['token'])){
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);

}
if($client->getAccessToken()){

    $snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
    $snippet->setTitle('Test après midi');
    $snippet->setDescription('Petite description');
    $snippet->setTags(['tag1','tag2']);
    $snippet->setCategoryId(17);

    $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
    $status->setPrivacyStatus('private');


    $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
    $video->setSnippet($snippet);
    $video->setStatus($status);

    $request = $youtube->videos->insert('status,snippet', $video);

} else {
    $html = '<div class="panel panel-danger">
            <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2>Accès interdit</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
            <p> Vous devez <a href="' . $client->createAuthUrl() . '"> autoriser</a> l\'application à accéder à votre compte youtube.</p>
            </div> 
        </div>';
}
```

And this is what I get as a response

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "authError", "message": "Invalid Credentials", "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" } ], "code": 401, "message": "Invalid Credentials" } } ' in /home/foo/public_html/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php:118 Stack trace: #0 /home/foo/public_html/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php(94): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...') #1 [internal function]: Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...') #2 /home/foo/public_html/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Task/Runner.php(181): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #3 /home/foo/public_html/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php(58): Google_Task_Runner->run() #4 /home/foo/public_html/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Goo in /home/foxo/public_html/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php on line 118
```

Has anyone encountered this issue ?

Thanks guys.

Love.